# Flutter: How to check what is the previous route in navigator?

Tags: flutter, dart

I can go to route 'C' from both routes 'A' and 'B'. When I press back button on 'C' I want to make different api calls if I go back to 'A' or 'B'.

Comment: seems you need a `RouteObserver`

Comment: sorry, i meant its base class: `NavigatorObserver` - it has `void didPop(Route route,
Route previousRoute)` method

Comment: Yes, this is what I used :)

Comment: ok, you could post a self answer then, maybe it will be useful for other people

Answer (score 0):

The solution is RouteAware - it has didPopNext method.